# Dynamic PHP Microsites from Images In Directory

Tags: php, arrays, image

I'm looking to create microsites from images/files in a directory on my server:

- I take the images on my computer
- ftp them to a folder on my server
- person inputs email/text and receives a link to a dynamic html/php page on my 
  site where they can view/download the image/gif/mp4 they just took

I've seen it done and the novice hacker in me would like to do it for my job. It doesn't seem difficult but I'm not sure where to start. What is the basic architecture for this?

My site is made with php and right now the images are being FTP'ed to an images folder in public html. Where does the web page go? Same directory? How do I configure URL?

I'm totally with getting my hands dirty and learning so please share any basic code and links to check to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have everything you need to validate:

Link is yoursite.com/getimage.php?f=filename

Ideally, you'd hash the filename somehow. Just so it's not easily guessable.

Then your php looks like this

```
<?php
validateUserSomehow();
$filepath = "/path/to/file/".$_GET['f'];
echo '<img src="'.$filepath.'"/>';
?>
```

That will *literally* show only the image on the page. They can right click to download it.

Comment: If I throw this code on a page between my header and footer would it show as a full page with image?

Comment: Should do. Obviously, change it to suit your needs. Copying it straight will not work.

Comment: awesome it works. trying to figure how to validate and add a hash. Thanks!